# How to handle multi-level multipath inheritance in OOP?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

How can I handle a multi-level multipath inheritance situation (OOP in C++)?
For ex:

```
A
                
B       C
                    
D
                
E       F
                    
G
```

The above are given classes and their hierarchy can be understood as 'A' being the parent of 'B' and 'C' and 'D' being the parent of 'E' and 'F'. Now, 'D' is the child of 'B' and 'C' and similarly 'G' is the child of 'E' and 'F'.

Now, say if I create a variable of the class G, then I know that I can access the elements of E, F from G itself and also can access the elements of D from G using the scope resolution operator in C++. But how do I get higher and access the elements of B or C or even A from G itself using the scope resolution operator or say any other way if there is one?

Here's some C++ code that I used to implement this -

```
G obj;

obj.g = 1; // G's element
obj.e = 2; // E's element
obj.f = 3; // F's element

obj.E::d = 41; // Accessing D's element via E using scope resolution operator
obj.F::d = 42; // Accessing D's element via F using scope resolution operator
```

Now how do I go higher from here?

I then tried to access the higher elements in a similar fashion like this -

```
obj.E::D::b = 211; // First way I tried

obj.F.D::b = 212; // Second way I tried
```

The first one shows an error stating "'D' is an ambiguous base of 'G'" and the second one shows an error stating "invalid use of 'F::F'.

What is the right way to implement this and access elements that are even higher than this? Or is there any way possible to do so?

Comment: I'd suggest using composition over inheritance. I don't want to imagine the inheritance graph. Also if you meant multiple inheritance.. don't use it unless you're writing template.

Comment: If you really want an answer, please provide an [mre] for the given inheritance that compiles since the description might be interpreted in different ways. You may use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) to provide the sample code. A wall of descriptions is less clear than a snippet of code.

Comment: Stating requirements precisely is vital for implementing the solution. Please draw the class hierarchy in UML or just drop the code sample here. I'm guessing it's a diamond/virtual inheritance case, but it might be just my interpretation and without precise description one cannot be certain.

Comment: If D is a base of C and F and you want it to be unique, you need to make D inherit virtual. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this via accessors, but casting the type layer by layer works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct A{int a;};
struct B: public A{int b;};
struct C: public A{int c;};
struct D: public B, public C{int d;};
struct E: public D{int e;};
struct F: public D{int f;};
struct G: public E, public F {int g;};

int main (){
    G obj{};
    obj.g = 1;
    static_cast<E&>(obj).d = 41;
    static_cast<F&>(obj).d = 42;
    static_cast<B&>(static_cast<E&>(obj)).a = 43;
    std::cout << "g: " << obj.g << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d1: " << ((E&)obj).d << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d2: " << ((F&)obj).d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```